# Can we reconstruct the PDF of a variable with the given moments

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am new to statistics. At the moment, I am stuck by a question regarding to the PDF of a random variable.

I wonder whether there is a way to reconstruct the PDF with the given statistical moments?

The PDF can be equivalently represented by the statistical moments and I want to understand the contribution to the PDF (histogram) by the statistical moments of each order. My guess is that at a certain order the contribution of the higher order statistical moments are less significant than those of low-orders. One can (maybe) set the high-order terms zero (or equal to a Gaussian) and use this approximation to reconstruct the PDF (histogram). I hope there is a way to generate a random sample using the truncated moments.

Many thanks for your help

Juan

Comment: This is not possible in general as two different distributions may have the same moments.

Comment: Search for the famous 'The Moment Problem' on Wiki.

Comment: Hey Nejimban and Kavi, 

Indeed, it is possible that two PDFs have different distribution but have the same low-order statistics. Practically, we can always compare the moments of the higher-order till we find the difference. 

Can we say that we close the problem by setting the high-order terms zero, e.g., M_(i>5) = 0, where M_i is the ith order moment? 

Please let me know what you think.

Juan

Comment: @Juan I think your question remains interesting if, say, the pdf has compact support (in this case the distribution is characterized by the moments). To reconstruct the pdf one could express the Laplace transform from the moments and then try to invert it. I don't know how practical this could be.

Comment: Hi Nejimban, many many thanks for the reply. I am trying to understand the PDF of some turbulent system. In many cases, the PDF of the turbulence is strongly non-Gaussian. I am trying to see what low-order statistics would result the PDF. I will look into the Laplace transform. Many thanks for your help. Juan